# Can anyone explain a part of the moment.js diff method logic?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can anyone explain how the logic in moment.js's monthDiff works? Here's the excerpt of diff function.

```
function monthDiff(a, b) {
    if (a.date() < b.date()) {
        // end-of-month calculations work correct when the start month has more
        // days than the end month.
        return -monthDiff(b, a);
    }

    // !!! I DON'T UNDERSTAND FROM HERE BELOW !!!

    // difference in months
    var wholeMonthDiff = (b.year() - a.year()) * 12 + (b.month() - a.month()),
        // b is in (anchor - 1 month, anchor + 1 month) => Why? Any theory or Math formula?
        anchor = a.clone().add(wholeMonthDiff, 'months'),
        anchor2,
        adjust;

    if (b - anchor < 0) {
        anchor2 = a.clone().add(wholeMonthDiff - 1, 'months');
        // linear across the month
        adjust = (b - anchor) / (anchor - anchor2);
    } else {
        anchor2 = a.clone().add(wholeMonthDiff + 1, 'months');
        // linear across the month
        adjust = (b - anchor) / (anchor2 - anchor);
    }

    //check for negative zero, return zero if negative zero
    return -(wholeMonthDiff + adjust) || 0;
}
```

Ref:
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/diff.js

Comment: The following article helped me to grasp the idea of the calculation, though not fully understand it yet.
https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/date-time-math/

Comment: "*b is in (anchor - 1 month, anchor + 1 month) - why?*" - because that's just the worst estimate. It's very close to `anchor` itself, but might be a few days off, depending on the number of days of the respective months. Notice how `adjust` is computed - it's pretty much the same in both cases, except for the exact interval between `anchor` and `anchor2`.

Comment: @Bergi
Thank you so much for your comments. Do you have any idea on the adjustment calculation, "adjust = (b - anchor) / (anchor - anchor2) and adjust = (b - anchor) / (anchor2 - anchor)"?

Comment: What is there to say? It computes the fractional part of the month difference, "*linear across the month*" as the comment says. (Of course the whole thing is questionable - why choose the month of `b` instead of the month of `a` for this? But date math is hard)

Comment: I am just wondering the adjust computation is based on some theory or standard way. Anyway, I appreciated your comments.